# Js check if the location is in my site with cross domain

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have an iframe that linked to other site and when the user press a button there is redirect to my site inside the iframe.
I am checking now if the location is my address and base of this doing something. the problem is that when the location is still the other domain i get the cross domain error:

```
Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "http://localhost" from accessing a frame with origin "https://somesite.com".  The frame requesting access has a protocol of "http", the frame being accessed has a protocol of "https". Protocols must match.
```

How i can pass this error?

```
document.getElementById("paymentIframe").addEventListener('load', function() {

var url = document.getElementById("paymentIframe").contentWindow.location.href;

 if( url.indexOf('status') > -1 && url.indexOf('success') > -1 )
             //i am in my domain   
 });
```

Comment: why not notifying the parent window from within your iframe with javascript. If iframe redirects to your domain you can place some javascript in that page like `parent.functionName()`

Comment: How i am doing this?

Comment: create a function in your parent page `function helloFromParent(){alert('hello');}` Then in your iframe (the page on your domain) you can call `parent.helloFromParent()`

Comment: This will work in all browsers?

Comment: yes: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_parent.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably simplest to catch the error and retry again after a `setTimeout(..., 10)`, until it stops happening (perhaps with an upper limit; e.g., if you keep trying for more than 30 seconds, give up).

E.g.:

```
function checkForFrame(callback) {
    var timeout = Date.now() + 30000; // 30 seconds

    doCheck();

    function doCheck() {
        var url;

        try {
            url = document.getElementById("paymentIframe").contentWindow.location.href;
            if (url.indexOf('status') > -1 && url.indexOf('success') > -1)
                callback(true);
                return;
            }
        }
        catch (e) {
        }

        // The frame is inaccessible or the URL doesn't match; time out?
        if (Date.now() > timeout) {
            // Yup
            callback(false);
        } else {
            // Nope, try again in 10ms
            setTimeout(doCheck, 10);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you give an example how to write this please?

Comment: @JsIsAwesome: Okay, I've added one, but catching exceptions and using `setTimeout` are both really basic.